# Which one is the better sentence?

Tags: american-english

Which one is the better sentence?

1. The opportunity does not made by someone. The opportunity is things that I make.
2. Opportunities are not made by others. It is me that make the opportunities.
3. None. What else options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: your question should be "*Which one is the better sentence?*" or "*Which one is best?*. While "more better" seems good, you cannot use "more" with "better".

An example:

A new car is *better* than an old car.
A Lamborghini is the *best* car.

My car is *more green* than your car.
My car is the *most green*. = My car is *greenest*.

For your question, here is what I believe you are trying to say:

**1.**

> The opportunity is not made by someone else. The opportunity is made by me.

Saying "The opportunity" talks about only one, specific opportunity. To speak in general, you'll want to say "Opportunities", like you did in your second one. Saying "An opportunity" talks about one opportunity, but it is also general (because it is not a specific opportunity).

For your second phrase:

> The oppertunity is things that I make

You could also say:

> An opportunity is something that I make.

**2.**

> opportunities are not made by others it is me that make the  opportunities.

Here is your phrase with a little revising:

> Opportunities are not made by others; I make the opportunities.

I think you really improved upon your first idea in this one; it's much better.

**3.** 
A better way of phrasing it might be:

> Opportunities are not made by others, but by myself.

This one or the revised one from 2 are good.

Comment: @user1917217 Usually, that is true. Again, back to the car example: "A new car is better than an old car." This is the general format. But it can be rearranged. It's wrong to say "the more better sentence". Saying "This is the better sentence" is the same as "This sentence is better (than another)".

Comment: Thanks you are really good teacher. but you use "the" at better. As I know the is used at -est. Aren't you?

Comment: Also I have one more question about you used 'be' verb instead 'do' auxilary. Why?

Comment: It's all about what people normally say. Certain verbs and prepositions are used with certain phrases. With "made by", you will always say "something is made by something else" or "some things are made by something else". If I answered your question, please mark my answer as the answer! :)